# Reading dates as dates and not characters

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, plot

The data I have been working with reads everything just fine, **except** for the date column. It always reads it as characters instead.

This would be fine except that, when I have lots of dates (like over 400 of them), then you can see something like this on a scatterplot:

- [Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKQAG.png)

In essence, I have two questions.

1. The first is, apart from using `as.Date`, which is fine when I'm needed temporary stuff, how do I **permanently** make R read the date column as legit dates? What I mean is, is there a way I can make that date column read as dates when I am using `read.csv` or `read.excel`?
2. When graphing, like the graph I have included here, how can I only include some of the labels throughout so that it won't be so cramped up? I still want all the data, but really do not want all those labels.

I was hoping to add the data file, but I am unaware of how to add excel/csv files on this website and my data set is quite long (*n = 491*). I do have 9 columns, 1 of which is the date column. The others are numbers or actual letters (the latter of which is in fact a character). I can add maybe a few rows just to help out.

[Some of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ3Mt.png)

Comment: 1. read.csv has the option `colClasses` to specify what each column is. So something like"`read.csv(my_file, colClasses = c("numeric", "integer", "character", "integer", "integer", "integer", "integer", "Date", "integer")`.  2. use ggplot, the dates would be printed only on the breaks instead of every point as base plot does. Otherwise you have to overrule the default printing of the `xlab` with your own.

Comment: readxl is a great tool for reading in excel files. You can set the type that an excel column is read in as using col_types.

To add your dataset to a stack overflow post, DPUT works well.

For good axis layout defaults, ggplot2 is the best. You control ticks using scale_x_date.

Comment: Both gave me errors, sadly. Though the second comment, by @Isaiah, was a bit closer. 

Firstly, **THANKS TO YOU BOTH** for your help.

Second, here are the errors I got in order of the comments above.

1) Error in match.arg(numerals) : 'arg' should be one of "allow.loss", "warn.loss", "no.loss".

2) Error: Can't guess format of this cell reference: character.

Comment: It did work when placing the ```read_excel(Data, col_types = c("numeric", "numeric", "text", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "date", "date")```

Comment: Only problem is that now, the class for my date is "POSIXCT" "POSIXt" still.